# How clean bean fields on a flow scope when this finish?

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I got a annotated service bean which is used to store form values on *newSpace_1 page* when I navigate to another flow I wish cleaning this bean because if I return to *newSpace_1 page* I would like showing empty fields because I got navigate buttons that depend on the value of the fields.

I tried to declare this bean as var on flow definition and a @service bean, then set method works but get method retrieve null for each properties. So I need to use as @service for set/get methods work properly on *newSpace_1 page*.

```
<flow...>
   <var name="spaceFields" class="x.y.x.Spacields" />

  <view-state>
    ......
  </view-state>
</flow>
```

**SpaceFields**

```
@Service("spaceFields")
public class SpaceFields implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Min(value=1)
@Max(value=194)
private Integer idCountry;

@Min(value=1)
@Max(value=5)
private Integer idContinent;

....
....
```

}

**Flow definition**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    parent="commons-header">

<secured attributes="ROLE_USER" />

<view-state id="adminSpace" view="admin_spaces.xhtml">
    <transition on="new" to="step1" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="step1" view="newSpace_1.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="place.findContinents()" result="flowScope.continents" />
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="next" to="step2" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="step2" view="newSpace_2.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="category.findCategories()" result="flowScope.categories" />
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="back" to="step1" />
    <transition on="next" to="step3" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="step3" view="newSpace_3.xhtml">
    <transition on="back" to="step2" />
    <transition on="next" to="step4" />
</view-state>
```

**newSpace_1 code**

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/mainPage.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="${msg['newSpace.title']}"  />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="centerContainer">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_info" styleClass="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_info">
            <h1>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['newSpace.step1.main.header']}" />
            </h1>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_info_msg" styleClass="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_info_msg">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['newSpace.step1.main.msg']}" />
            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_fields" styleClass="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_fields">
                <h:outputLabel for="continent" value="#{msg['continent.txt']}" styleClass="labelInput" />

                <h:selectOneMenu id="continent" value="#{spaceFields.idContinent}" title="#{msg['continent.select.title']}" tabindex="1">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['continent.select.zeroption']}" itemValue="0" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems var="continent" value="#{continents}" itemLabel="#{continent.name}" itemValue="#{continent.primaryKey.continent.idContinent}" />
                    <f:ajax render="@this country messageContinentError"  listener="#{place.findCountries(flowRequestContext)}" event="change" />
                    <f:validateBean for="idContinent" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message id="messageContinentError" for="continent" styleClass="messageError" />

                <h:outputLabel for="country" value="#{msg['country.txt']}" styleClass="labelInput" />

                <h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{spaceFields.idCountry}" title="#{msg['country.select.title']}" tabindex="2">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['country.select.zeroption']}" itemValue="0" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems var="countryLocale" value="#{countries}" itemLabel="#{countryLocale.name}" itemValue="#{countryLocale.primaryKey.country.idCountry}"  />
                    <f:ajax render="@this -controls-creatingSpaceContainer_step1_controls messageCountryError" event="change" />
                    <f:validateBean for="idCountry" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message id="messageCountryError" for="country" styleClass="messageError" />      
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="controls">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_controls" styleClass="creatingSpaceContainer_step1_controls">
                <h:commandLink action="next" value="#{msg['next.button.txt']}" title="#{msg['next.button.title']}" alt="#{msg['next.button.alt']}" tabindex="3" rendered="#{spaceFields.idCountry>0}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on-exit action in the view state to clear the bean while navigating away from view as:

```
    <view-state id="step1" view="newSpace_1.xhtml">
        <on-entry>
            ....
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="next" to="step2">
        <on-exit>
            <evaluate expression="someaction.clear(flowScope.spaceFields)"/> 
        </on-exit>
    </view-state>
```

This way when you re-enter view all your bean fields are empty.

You can find more details about on-exit action [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/actions.html).

Comment: I was looking a more exact spring webflow way but I thinks this solution solves this problem. Instead a on-exit on view root I've written a on-end on flow root because so I can store fields in a wizard menu. Thank very much @Prasad!

Comment: @RafaelRuizTabares you are welcome and enjoy coding!